# Performant Threaded C++ Pixel Rendering: Fastest Way?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, rendering, pixel

My goal is simple: I want to create a rendering system in C++ that can draw thousands of bitmaps on screen.  I have been trying to use threads to speed up the process but to no avail.  In most cases, I have actually slowed down performance by using multiple threads.  I am using this project as an educational exercise by not using hardware acceleration.  That said, my question is this:

What is the best way to use several threads to accept a massive list of images to be drawn onto the screen and render them at break-neck speeds?  I know that I won’t be able to create a system that can rival hardware accelerated graphics, but I believe that my idea is still feasible because the operation is so simple: copying pixels from one memory location to another.

My renderer design uses three core blitting operations:  position, rotation, and scale of a bitmap image.  I have it set up to only rotate an image when needed, and only scale an image when needed.

I have gone through several designs for this system.  All of them too slow to get the job done (300 64x64 bitmaps at barely 60fps).

Here are the designs I have tried:

1. Immediately drawing a source bitmap on a destination bitmap for every image on screen (moderate speed).
2. Creating workers that accept a draw instruction and immediately begin working on it while other workers receive their instructions also (slowest).
3. Workers that receive packages of several instructions at a time (slower).
4. Saving all drawing instructions up and then parting them up in one swoop to several workers while other tasks (in theory) are being done (slowest).

Here is the bitmap class I am using to blit bitmaps onto each other:

```
class Bitmap
{
public:
    Bitmap(int w, int h)
    {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        size = w * h;
        pixels = new unsigned int[size];
    }

    virtual ~Bitmap()
    {
        if (pixels != 0)
        {
            delete[] pixels;
            pixels = 0;
        }
    }

    void blit(Bitmap *bmp, float x, float y, float rot, float sclx,
        float scly)
    {
        // Position only
        if (rot == 0 && sclx == 1 && scly == 1)
        {
            blitPos(bmp, x, y);
            return;
        }

        // Rotate only
        else if (rot != 0 && sclx == 1 && scly == 1)
        {
            blitRot(bmp, x, y, rot);
            return;
        }

        // Scale only
        else if (rot == 0 && (sclx != 1 || scly != 1))
        {
            blitScl(bmp, x, y, sclx, scly);
            return;
        }


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // If it is not one of those, you have to do all three... :D
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Create a bitmap that is scaled to the new size.
        Bitmap tmp((int)(bmp->width * sclx), (int)(bmp->height * scly));

        // Find how much each pixel steps:
        float step_x = (float)bmp->width / (float)tmp.width;
        float step_y = (float)bmp->height / (float)tmp.height;

        // Fill the scaled image with pixels!
        float inx = 0;
        int xOut = 0;
        while (xOut < tmp.width)
        {
            float iny = 0;
            int yOut = 0;

            while (yOut < tmp.height)
            {
                unsigned int sample = bmp->pixels[
                    (int)(std::floor(inx) + std::floor(iny) * bmp->width)
                ];

                tmp.drawPixel(xOut, yOut, sample);

                iny += step_y;
                yOut++;
            }
            inx += step_x;
            xOut++;
        }

        blitRot(&tmp, x, y, rot);
    }

    void drawPixel(int x, int y, unsigned int color)
    {
        if (x > width || y > height || x < 0 || y < 0)
            return;
        if (color == 0x00000000)
            return;
        int index = x + y * width;
        if (index >= 0 && index <= size)
            pixels[index] = color;
    }

    unsigned int getPixel(int x, int y)
    {
        return pixels[x + y * width];
    }

    void clear(unsigned int color)
    {
        std::fill(&pixels[0], &pixels[size], color);
    }

    private:
    void blitPos(Bitmap *bmp, float x, float y)
    {
        // Don't draw if coordinates are already past edges
        if (x > width || y > height || y + bmp->height < 0 || x + bmp->width < 0)
            return;

        int from;
        int to;
        int destfrom;
        int destto;
        for (int i = 0; i < bmp->height; i++)
        {
            from = i * bmp->width;
            to = from + bmp->width;

            //////// Caps

            // Bitmap is being drawn past the right edge
            if (x + bmp->width > width)
            {
                int cap = bmp->width - ((x + bmp->width) - width);
                to = from + cap;
            }

            // Bitmap is being drawn past the left edge
            else if (x + bmp->width < bmp->width)
            {
                int cap = bmp->width + x;
                from += (bmp->width - cap);
                to = from + cap;
            }

            //////// Destination Maths

            if (x < 0)
            {
                destfrom = (y + i) * width;
                destto = destfrom + (bmp->width + x);
            }

            else
            {
                destfrom = x + (y + i) * width;
                destto = destfrom + bmp->width;
            }

            // Bitmap is being drawn past either top or bottom edges
            if (y + i > height - 1)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (destfrom > size || destfrom < 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            memcpy(&pixels[destfrom], &bmp->pixels[from], sizeof(unsigned int) * (to - from));
        }
    }

    void blitRot(Bitmap *bmp, float x, float y, float rot)
    {
        float sine = std::sin(-rot);
        float cosine = std::cos(-rot);

        int x1 = (int)(-bmp->height * sine);
        int y1 = (int)(bmp->height * cosine);
        int x2 = (int)(bmp->width * cosine - bmp->height * sine);
        int y2 = (int)(bmp->height * cosine + bmp->width * sine);
        int x3 = (int)(bmp->width * cosine);
        int y3 = (int)(bmp->width * sine);

        int minx = (int)std::min(0, std::min(x1, std::min(x2, x3)));
        int miny = (int)std::min(0, std::min(y1, std::min(y2, y3)));
        int maxx = (int)std::max(0, std::max(x1, std::max(x2, x3)));
        int maxy = (int)std::max(0, std::max(y1, std::max(y2, y3)));

        int w = maxx - minx;
        int h = maxy - miny;

        int srcx;
        int srcy;
        int dest_x;
        int dest_y;
        unsigned int color;

        for (int sy = miny; sy < maxy; sy++)
        {
            for (int sx = minx; sx < maxx; sx++)
            {
                srcx = sx * cosine + sy * sine;
                srcy = sy * cosine - sx * sine;

                dest_x = x + sx;
                dest_y = y + sy;

                if (dest_x <= width - 1 && dest_y <= height - 1
                    && dest_x >= 0 && dest_y >= 0)
                {
                    color = 0;

                    // Only grab a pixel if it is inside of the src image
                    if (srcx < bmp->width && srcy < bmp->height && srcx >= 0 &&
                        srcy >= 0)
                        color = bmp->getPixel(srcx, srcy);

                    // Only this pixel if it is not completely transparent:
                    if (color & 0xFF000000)

                        // Only if the pixel is somewhere between 0 and the bmp size
                        if (0 < srcx < bmp->width && 0 < srcy < bmp->height)
                            drawPixel(x + sx, y + sy, color);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void blitScl(Bitmap *bmp, float x, float y, float sclx, float scly)
    {
        // Create a bitmap that is scaled to the new size.
        int finalwidth = (int)(bmp->width * sclx);
        int finalheight = (int)(bmp->height * scly);

        // Find how much each pixel steps:
        float step_x = (float)bmp->width / (float)finalwidth;
        float step_y = (float)bmp->height / (float)finalheight;

        // Fill the scaled image with pixels!

        float inx = 0;
        int xOut = 0;
        float iny;
        int yOut;
        while (xOut < finalwidth)
        {
            iny = 0;
            yOut = 0;

            while (yOut < finalheight)
            {
                unsigned int sample = bmp->pixels[
                    (int)(std::floor(inx) + std::floor(iny) * bmp->width)
                ];

                drawPixel(xOut + x, yOut + y, sample);

                iny += step_y;
                yOut++;
            }
            inx += step_x;
            xOut++;
        }
    }

public:
    int width;
    int height;
    int size;
    unsigned int *pixels;
};
```

Here is some code showing the latest method I have tried: saving up all instructions and then giving them to workers once they have all been received:

```
class Instruction
{
    public:
    Instruction() {}

    Instruction(Bitmap* out, Bitmap* in, float x, float y, float rot,
        float sclx, float scly)
        : outbuffer(out), inbmp(in), x(x), y(y), rot(rot),
        sclx(sclx), scly(scly)
    { }

    ~Instruction()
    {
        outbuffer = nullptr;
        inbmp = nullptr;
    }

public:
    Bitmap* outbuffer;
    Bitmap* inbmp;
    float x, y, rot, sclx, scly;
};
```

Layer Class:

```
class Layer
{
public:
    bool empty()
    {
        return instructions.size() > 0;
    }

public:
    std::vector<Instruction> instructions;
    int pixel_count;
};
```

Worker Thread Class:

```
class Worker
{
public:
    void start()
    {
        done = false;
        work_thread = std::thread(&Worker::processData, this);
    }

    void processData()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            controller.lock();
            if (done)
            {
                controller.unlock();
                break;
            }

            if (!layers.empty())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < layers.size(); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < layers[i].instructions.size(); j++)
                    {
                        Instruction* inst = &layers[i].instructions[j];
                        inst->outbuffer->blit(inst->inbmp, inst->x, inst->y, inst->rot, inst->sclx, inst->scly);
                    }
                }
                layers.clear();
            }
            controller.unlock();
        }
    }

    void finish()
    {
        done = true;
    }

public:
    bool done;
    std::thread work_thread;
    std::mutex controller;
    std::vector<Layer> layers;
};
```

Finally, the Render Manager Class:

```
class RenderManager
{
public:
    RenderManager()
    {
        workers.reserve(std::thread::hardware_concurrency());

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            workers.emplace_back();
            workers.back().start();
        }
    }

    void layer()
    {
        layers.push_back(current_layer);
        current_layer = Layer();
    }

    void blit(Bitmap* out, Bitmap* in, float x, float y, float rot, float sclx, float scly)
    {
        current_layer.instructions.emplace_back(out, in, x, y, rot, sclx, scly);
    }

    void processInstructions()
    {
        if (layers.empty())
            layer();
        lockall();
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < layers.size(); i++)
        {
            // Evenly distribute the layers in a round-robin fashion
            Layer l = layers[i];
            workers[index].layers.push_back(layers[i]);
            index++;
            if (index >= workers.size()) index = 0;
        }
        layers.clear();
        unlockall();
    }

    void lockall()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < workers.size(); i++)
        {
            workers[i].controller.lock();
        }
    }

    void unlockall()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < workers.size(); i++)
        {
            workers[i].controller.unlock();
        }
    }

    void finish()
    {
        // Wait until every worker is done rendering
        lockall();
        // At this point, we know they have nothing more to draw
        unlockall();
    }

    void endRendering()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < workers.size(); i++)
        {
            // Send each one an exit code
            workers[i].finish();
        }

        // Let the workers finish and then return
        for (int i = 0; i < workers.size(); i++)
        {
            workers[i].work_thread.join();
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<Worker> workers;
    std::vector<Layer> layers;
    Layer current_layer;
};
```

Here is a screenshot of what the 3rd method I tried, and it's results:
[Sending packages of draw instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr07g.png)

What would really be helpful is that if someone could simply point me in the right direction in regards to what method I should try.  I have tried these four methods and have failed, so I stand before those who have done greater things than I for help.  The least intelligent person in the room is the one that does not ask questions because his pride does not permit it.  Please keep in mind though, this is my first question ever on Stack Overflow.

Comment: From your picture. Dont do perf tests in _Debug_ configuration, any performance tests should always be in some kind of optimised (e.g. _Release_) flavor.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! :D You are totally correct!

Comment: where's the bottleneck? I would have thought it's the rotations. Perhaps parallelise those (and maybe cache the rotated sprite?). parallelising the actual blits to screen will be problematic because presumably you'll want a deterministic blit order so you can represent depth?

Comment: At first I would have thought so too. It turns out that scaling (as well as rotations) are slowing it down tremendously. By caching the rotated sprite, what do you mean? And yes, I have to have a way of preserving or at least controlling blit order.

Comment: No answers? :[ I have been continuing to work on this system and have been able to make the scaling algorithm more performant. All I need to do now is to find a way to rotate a bitmap around its center in a fast way.